# Formatting ISO8601 date/time into number field

Tags: jq, formatdatetime

I am trying to use the following to format my data from date/time to a number field however it is passing me an error

Field
 `"test": (.int.example_t | formatdate iso8601 | tonumber)`

Error
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 13: "test": (.int.example_t | formatdate iso8601 | tonumber) jq: 1 compile error

Any idea any other ways to change the formatting?

So far I've only tried using

Field
 `"test": (.int.example_t | formatdate iso8601 | tonumber)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead **formatdate** (is not a built-in **jq** function) use the UNIX timestamp:

```
jq '{ "test": (.int.example_t | todate // 0 | tonumber) }' input.json
```

**todate** function converts the date/time string to a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: awesome, tried this and appears to be working thank you